# Alinhamento horizontal entre 2 colunas

Tags: css

Olá, eu gostaria de fazer o alinhamento de forma sincronizada dessas 2 div's.

ONDE EU QUERO CHEGAR:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ONDE EU ESTOU CHEGANDO:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código fonte:

```css
#terceira-sessao {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.terceira-sessao-titulo {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 52.7059px;
    line-height: 64px;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.7px;
}

.terceira-sessao-subtitulo {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.input-texto {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 54px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(101deg, #78e4ff, #ff48fa);
    border-width: 5pt;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    background-origin: border-box;
    border: solid 3px transparent;
    box-shadow: 2px 1000px 1px #333333 inset;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

.input-texto:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.terceira-sessao-formulario {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

.terceira-sessao-formulario-submeter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 11px;
}
```

```html
<section id="terceira-sessao">
        <div class="terceira-sessao">
            <h1 class="titulo terceira-sessao-titulo">INTERESTED IN VR?</h1>
            <a class="terceira-sessao-subtitulo">Fill out a short form and we will call you back</a>
        </div>

        <div class="terceira-sessao-formulario">
            <input class="input-texto terceira-sessao-formulario-nome" type="text">
            <input class="input-texto terceira-sessao-formulario-numero" type="text">
            <input class="input-texto terceira-sessao-formulario-email" type="text">

        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, o que eu penso para deixar os os dois com a mesma distância é e apagar a propriedade "justify-content: center;" da classe ".terceira-sessao-formulario", dai os dois vão colar na esquerda, como está na foto 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois vamos no html e colocalos todos os dentro de uma div container, exceto a section. Para essa div container definimos um width, e colocamos margin auto. Vamos obter o resultado da foto 2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem se esse seria o resultado final que você gostaria paramos por aqui, porém se você quiser que os botões ocupem todo o espaço toda a largura, basta definirmos a flex-grow:1 para cada um deles ou fazer dessa forma ".terceira-sessao-formulario *:nth-child(n){flex-grow: 1;}" e vamos ter o resultado da foto 3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS1: você pode colocar o flex-grow para cada elemento dentro de ".terceira-sessao-formulario", porem eu acho mais fácil usar o ".terceira-sessao-formulario*:nth-child(n)" por que dai você muda todos os "filhos" da classe .terceira-sessao-formulario de uma só vez.

OBS2: no código original, na classe ".terceira-sessao-formulario", você está usando a propriedade "align-items: stretch;", porém ela se refere ao eixo tranversal, que nesse caso está na horizontal, traduzindo, é como se vc quisesse esticar os botões para cima e pra baixar, invés de pros lados.

Esse é o código HTML final:

```
<section id="terceira-sessao">
<div class="container">
                <div class="terceira-sessao">
                        <h1 class="titulo terceira-sessao-titulo">INTERESTED IN VR?</h1>
                        <a class="terceira-sessao-subtitulo">Fill out a short form and we will call you back</a>
                </div>

                <div class="terceira-sessao-formulario">
                        <input class="input-texto terceira-sessao-formulario-nome" type="text">
                        <input class="input-texto terceira-sessao-formulario-numero" type="text">
                        <input class="input-texto terceira-sessao-formulario-email" type="text">

                </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Esse é o CSS final:

```
#terceira-sessao {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.terceira-sessao-titulo {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 52.7059px;
    line-height: 64px;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.7px;
}

.terceira-sessao-subtitulo {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.input-texto {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 54px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(101deg, #78e4ff, #ff48fa);
    border-width: 5pt;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    background-origin: border-box;
    border: solid 3px transparent;
    box-shadow: 2px 1000px 1px #333333 inset;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

.input-texto:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.terceira-sessao-formulario {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
    align-items: stretch; /*Acredito que essa propriedade seja desnecessária*/
     /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.terceira-sessao-formulario-submeter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 11px;
}


/*CSS ADICIONADO*/
.container {
    width: 900px;/* Essa largura foi só um exemplo, você tem quer ver qual se encaixa melhor no seu caso*/
    margin: auto;
}

.terceira-sessao-formulario *:nth-child(n){
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito!! Funcionou exatamente como eu queria. Muito obrigado!!